# magento getOptionId not working for some labels

Tags: php, magento

I'm using the below code to get the option id for `attribute set "size"`.
It is returning correct id if I use option label greater than 9 (i.e, 10,12,13,14 ..)

But is not working if use option label less than 10 (i.e, 5,6,7,8,9).

```
$attr = 'size';
$attribute_label = 13;
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attribute_name = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_name);

if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    echo $color_id = $attribute_name->getSource()-  >getOptionId($attribute_label);
}
```

**Example:**

> Output when I use option label ($attribute_label = 13)  as 13 it
>   returns 5.
>
> Output when I use option label ($attribute_label = 6)  as 6 it returns
>   6.

Comment: You can try below post http://magentorex.com/magento-get-product-attributes-option-id-from-option-label/

Answer (score 1):

This happens because getOptionId() does not work well with numeric labels, as stated also in this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128445/getoptionid-method-returns-invalid-option-id

What you can do is to avoid using this method and adjust your code something like:

```
$attribute_name = 'size';
$attribute_label = 13;
$optionId = false;
$attr = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute($attribute_name);
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attr->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    foreach($options as $option) {
        if($option['label'] == $attribute_label) {
            $optionId = $option['value'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```